# QEMU build error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qemu

I am trying to build QEMU for the power pc target and I am getting the following 2 errors when I build.

```
unknown type name ‘fdt64_t’
unknown type name ‘fdt32_t’
```

The qemu version is 0.12.0 and I got it from here, http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/qemu/. To build, I run

```
./configure -target-list=ppc-softmmu
make
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.12.0 is an incredibly ancient version of QEMU, and that download page is also well out of date, since it has no releases later than 2011. You should start by getting a more recent QEMU from the official download page: http://wiki.qemu.org/Download

Comment: I ended up going this route a day or two back. Less headache! Thanks.